# DNN Scheduler won't run my custom schedule

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I have created a class Library  and made sure it inherits

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.SchedulerClient
```

And have then overrided the DoWork() sub.

Then in dnn host settings > scheduler added a new scheduler Item.

in the textbox marked : Full Class Name and Assembly:

```
Namespace.Classname, Dllname
```

checked the Enable Schedule box and added a run time interval of 5mins and enabled catch up.

also added the list of tables that the class uses. and keep 5 records of history

I then saved it,

In the view schedule Status I get this:

```
Name          |  Next Start              |  OverDue(s)  | Time Remaining
Sub reminder  |  11/12/2010 9:52:02 AM   |  3.5         |  0
```

Using the scheduler in request mode.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Update :

Ok, I created a new class library project called "SubRenewal"
Renamed the vb file Test and added the below to the file

```
Namespce Matts
 Public Class Test
  Inherits Dnn.Services.Scheduling.SchedulerClient
   Public overrides Sub DoWork()
     Me.ScheduleHistoryItem.addLogNote("I ran")
   end Sub
 End Class
End Namespace
```

On the Scheduler Page I put :
Friendly Name Tester
Full Class name and assembly Matts.Test,SubRenwal
Enabled Yes
Time Lapse 10 s
Rety frequency -
Run on Event None
And left everything else blank and saved it. Still nothing in Scheduler or Item History. Also theres nothing in the event viewer

Comment: check out the schedule history

Comment: The standard DNN Schedules run fine. Mine doesnt show up at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly Id Like to thank Lakhlan, for his help without him I wouldnt of spotted the mistake.

I beleive the issue was one of two things first one is that I was registering a reference to another custom module to allow me to localise some of the output text.

Also I added the new constructor below

```
Public Sub New(ByVal objSceduleHistoryItem As DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.ScheduleHistoryItem)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.ScheduleHistoryItem = objSceduleHistoryItem
    End Sub
```

Thanks again would up vote you for your help but cant :(

Comment: No worries, I'm glad your problem is now resolved. Please mark your answer as solution in order to mark the problem resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest following steps to get started with scheduler development and debugging:

- Create a new class library probject and add reference of dotnetnuke and related dlls in it
- add reference of the same project to your dnn project
- add a new vb or c# file to implement scheduler
- add code lines to create entries in schedule history and no other code
- test your scheduler
- register your new scheduler from dotentnuke website host account

Please note that as soon as you add a new scheduler item, it will fire the scheduler.
I hope this will help you. I will suggest to remove the entry of scheduler you already having, reset your website instance ( iis or asp.net development server) and try adding it again using the above method

Hope this will help you